# Cannot save document to usb

Tags: usb, files

Unable to save any OpenOffice documents to usb. Cannot export any Picasa pictures to external hard-drive either.

Message says: Error saving the document..... does not exist.
.... is file name

Comment: A screenshot would be useful.

Comment: yes screenshot will help you to get your answer